# alfresco add new action to document library at last index

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have a question regarding Alfresco Share community 5.2.

I have serveral (2 for now) differents share amps to be deployed on the same alfresco server and both of the amps adds new action to document's detail page.
Normally I would have set the action index manually, to avoid conflicts, but those amps could be disabled or added "dynamically"

How can I configure them to add their action button at the end of the action's list independently of how many actions are already there?

Basically each other amps which adds new actions to the document library will put its action at the last index inside the document library

[image]

I'm not shure this is the correct approach, my need is to be as modular as I can.

Comment: Please provide the highest index number for them. I don't think you make can dynamic index numbers for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, you can provide the highest index number for them, in case of two identical numbers (i.e. you have 3 actions on 601 index) all of them are added sequentially and between 600 and 602 index.

By the way, if you need more accuracy to place the buttons in a very specific place, you can specify the position in the enclosing amp documentlibrary-actions-config.xml.